# How can I find records using only certain rows in a joined table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB with this layout...

```
contracts
---------
id
name
description
# Etc...

locations
---------
id
contract_id  # FK to contracts.id
name
order_position
# Etc...
```

I need to find contracts by the `name` of their current location (and by other `contracts` columns at the same time).

The current location is the one with the greatest `order_position`.

In other words, I'm trying to write a query that will return rows from `contracts` based on `location.name`.

Ordinarily that would just be a simple join via `location.contract_id` and `contracts.id`.

For example, this would be the simple case, without the additional requirement...

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contracts c, locations l
WHERE
  c.id = l.contract_id
AND
  c.name LIKE '%bay%'
AND
  l.name LIKE '%admin%';
```

But the additional requirement is that I want to narrow it down to the contract's location that has the greatest value for `order_position`.

Is there a way to do that with one query?

Comment: Can you please add example data and expected output?

Comment: Table structure? Indexes? Database engine? Explain Plan? Data columes? Index cardinality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on it some more and found that this solves the problem...

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contracts c, locations l
WHERE
  c.id = l.contract_id
AND
  c.name LIKE '%bay%'
AND
  l.name LIKE '%admin%'
AND l.order_position =
(
  SELECT MAX(order_position)
  FROM `locations`
  WHERE `contract_id` = c.id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
 SELECT c.name FROM contracts c JOIN locations l ON c.id=l.contract_id 
 AND c.name IN(SELECT name FROM locations 
 WHERE locations.order_position IN(SELECT MAX(order_position) FROM locations GROUP BY locations.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.name, 
       loc2.name,
       loc2.order_position
  FROM dbo.contracts c
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT loc.contract_id,
               MAX(loc.order_position) AS order_position
      FROM locations loc
     GROUP BY contract_id
        ) loc
    ON c.id = loc.contract_id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.locations loc2
    ON loc2.contract_id = loc.contract_id
   AND loc2.order_position = loc.order_position
```